# python script to split date and time in a log file

Tags: python

I have the date and time in a log file like this `[01/Jan/2011:11:12:38 -0500]`. I want to split like `01/Jan/2011` and `11:12:38 -0500`. Please help me as how to split this using python code.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried and the problems you're having with that code.  This isn't `please-write-this-for-me.com`.

Comment: Use a regular expression or split the string after the n-th character (end of the year string)....which is basic Python ...no interest for writing such basic code...

Comment: Also.  Why split them?  If you use `datetime.datetime.strptime()` you don't need to split anything.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> "01/Jan/2011:11:12:38 -0500".split(":",1)
['01/Jan/2011', '11:12:38 -0500']
>>>
```